# Calculate $\int_\alpha e^{z^2+z+1}+e^{Im(z)} \ dz $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

Calculate $$\int_\alpha e^{z^2+z+1}+e^{Im(z)} \ dz $$

$\alpha$ is the square of vertices: $$0,1,i,i+1$$

Different segments: $$\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$$

$\alpha_i: [0,1] \rightarrow\mathbb{C}$

$$\alpha_1(t)=t$$
$$\alpha_2(t)=1+it$$
$$\alpha_3(t)=t+i$$
$$\alpha_4(t)=it$$

$$\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3-\alpha_4$$


$$\int_0^1 f(\alpha(t)) \ \alpha'(t) \ dt$$

I don't know how to calculate $f(\alpha(t))$ in this case: $e^{Im(z)}$.

$$\int_{\alpha_1} e^{z^2+z+1}+e^{Im(z)} \ dz=\int_0^1 e^{t^2+t+1}+e^{t} \ dt ?$$

Could I have any help, please?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is problem in $\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have \begin{align}
\alpha_1(t)&=t\\
\alpha_2(t)&=1+ti\\
\alpha_3(t)&=1-t+i\\
\alpha_4(t)&=(1-t)i\\
&\text{where $0\leq t\leq1$}
         \end{align}

We have to evaluate $\int_\alpha (e^{z^2+z+1}+e^{Im(z)} )\ dz=\int_\alpha e^{Im(z)} \ dz$,since $e^{z^2+z+1}$ is analytic inside the rectangle.

Now,\begin{align}
\int_\alpha e^{Im(z)} \ dz&=\int_{\alpha_1} e^{Im(z)} \ dz+\int_{\alpha _2} e^{Im(z)} \ dz+\int_{\alpha_ 3} e^{Im(z)} \ dz+\int_{\alpha_ 4} e^{Im(z)} \ dz\\
&=\int_0^1e^0dt+\int_0^1ie^tdt+\int_0^1-e dt+\int_0^1-ie^{1-t}dt\\
&=1+i(e-1)+(-e)+(-i)(e-1)\\
&=1-e
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy:

$\int_\alpha e^{z^2+z+1} \ dz=0$.

Hence you only have to compute the integral

$\int_\alpha e^{Im(z)} \ dz$.